# Long strings with newlines

Tags: c++, string

I have seen C# code that uses the `@` to tell the compiler the string has newlines in it and that it should be all in one line.
Is there something like that for C/C++?

Like if I want to put something like:

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

In a string I don't want to place it all in one line but just put it like that and have the compiler know that that is only one line.

Comment: @AntonioCS, what are you working on that you're using such big numbers and such long strings?  Are you working on some sort of compiler test suite? Just curious. :-)

Comment: Working on Project Euler I see.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C and C++ have automatic concatenation of adjacent quoted strings. This means that

```
const char *a = "a" "b";
```

and

```
const char *b = "ab";
```

will make `a` and `b` point at identical data. You can of course extend this, but it becomes troublesome when the strings contain quotes. Your example seems not to, so it might be practical then.

Answer (score 18):

C and C++ didn't have anything like C# verbatim string literals at the time this answer was first written. The closest you could do is:

```
"73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
"96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" 
"85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"  
"12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" 
"66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" 
"62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" 
"30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" 
"70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" 
"65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"  
"52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" 
"53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" 
"83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" 
"82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" 
"16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"  
"17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
"24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" 
"07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" 
"84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" 
"05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"     
"71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"
```

Note however that even in C# it doesn't do what it sounds like you want. If you have:

```
string foo = @"x
y";
```

in C# then the string will actually contain a linebreak.

In C++11, as per the comment, the `R` prefix denotes a *raw string literal*, e.g.

```
string x = R"(First line
second line)";
```

Comment: [time flies](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and good ideas are infectious

Answer (score 7):

In C and C++ you can do this:

```
const char* str = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                  "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843";
```

and the compiler will automatically concatenate these into a single string.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is to end a line with a \, upon seeing which the preprocessor will delete the following newline:

```
const char *str = "Hello,\
 World!";
```

It's not as pretty as relying on the automatic concatenation of adjacent string literals as said above; but should be mentioned anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can do:

```
char *x = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\n"
          "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\n"
                     <lines removed for brevity>
          "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
```

and this will emulate the @"" behavior exactly (including the line breaks).

If you really want it as one line with no line breaks, don't put the "\n" newline characters in, but that's slightly different to the way the @"" stuff works in C#.

Comment: Upvoted this answer since it has the \n for the line breaks included - which the OP seems to want. (but I wonder if he could live without?)