# Does VB.NET optimize the concatenation of string literals?

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, optimization

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288794/does-c-optimize-the-concatenation-of-string-literals) question, but for VB.NET since I learned this is a language thing.

For instance, would the compiler know to translate

> Dim s As String = "test " + "this " +
>   "function"

to

```
Dim s As String = "test this function"
```

and thus avoid the performance hit with the string concatenation?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. It Does. I only tested VS 2008 but I strongly suspect previous versions did as well.

VB.NET

```
Public Class Class1


    Dim s As String = "test " + "this " + "function"

    Public Function test() As String
        Return s
    End Function

End Class
```

I.L. - Notice the string "test this function"

```
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    L_0006: nop 
    L_0007: ldarg.0 
    L_0008: ldstr "test this function"
    L_000d: stfld string ClassLibrary1.Class1::s
    L_0012: nop 
    L_0013: ret 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**YES, IT DOES! LET`S PUT IT TO TEST.**

Since .NET compiles all managed languages (VB, C#, C++) to IL (Intermediate Language) instructions and `String` type is part of CLS (Common Language Specification) all .NET Framework versions: 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 optimizes `String` literals concatenation as a part of compilation process.

For instance VB.NET code below:

```
Dim s As String = "A" & "B" & "C"
```

produces the following IL instruction:

```
L_0008: ldstr "ABC"
```

This clearly proves that compiler is optimizing `String` literal concatenation (tested in: ildasm.exe)

However if the code obove is written in separate statements:

```
Dim s As String = "A"
s &= "B"
s &= "C"
```

no optimization is done and `String` concatenation is executed at run-time (performance overhead). Same applies for a single line statements with data resolved at run-time (variables, properties, methods).

Use underscore _ to connect above statements into a single statement to enforce optimization:

```
Dim s As String = "A" _
& "B" _
& "C" _
```

and in case you need new lines between tokens use `vbCrLf` (compile-time) constant to ensure optimization because using `Environment.NewLine` (run-time) property provides no optimization.

**Hope this helps you to get edge on performance!**

Answer (score 4):

While I'm looking it up, [here's the download page for the spec](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=39DE1DD0-F775-40BF-A191-09F5A95EF500&displaylang=en).

Section 11.2 looks like it *would* be the right bit - it's basically the equivalent of 7.18 in the C# 3.0 spec - but it doesn't contain the same guarantee. I suspect the compiler still does it, but I can't see any guarantee. I'll have another look though.

Section 11.2 does state that "A constant expression is an expression *whose value can be fully evaluated at compile time*" (my emphasis) but I can't see that it actually guarantees that it *will* fully evaluate it at compile time. Frankly it would be odd to make a category of expression based on this condition but not actually use it.

A quick test shows that the current VB compiler does indeed do the concatenation at compile time, but there really *should* be a guarantee in the spec if that's the intention.

Section 7.3 get a bit closer:

> When the operands of an expression are
>   all primitive type constants, it is
>   possible for the compiler to evaluate
>   the expression at compile time. Such
>   an expression is known as a constant
>   expression.

Now String isn't a primitive type in terms of the CLR ([Type.IsPrimitive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) would return false) but it *is* in terms of the VB spec.

It's still not saying that it *will* evaluate it though...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will optimize a string concatenation when appropriate. However, you should consider using the StringBuilder class if you don't know how many concatenations there may be.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

From the above article:

> The performance of a concatenation
>   operation for a String or
>   StringBuilder object depends on how
>   often a memory allocation occurs. A
>   String concatenation operation always
>   allocates memory, whereas a
>   StringBuilder concatenation operation
>   only allocates memory if the
>   StringBuilder object buffer is too
>   small to accommodate the new data.
>   Consequently, the String class is
>   preferable for a concatenation
>   operation if a fixed number of String
>   objects are concatenated. In that
>   case, the individual concatenation
>   operations might even be combined into
>   a single operation by the compiler. A
>   StringBuilder object is preferable for
>   a concatenation operation if an
>   arbitrary number of strings are
>   concatenated; for example, if a loop
>   concatenates a random number of
>   strings of user input.

Answer (score 1):

Jeff Atwood researched and blogged about this. Results?

[It. Just. Doesn't. Matter!](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)