# What is the correct syntax in c# to create a line break in the middle of a mysql string?

Tags: c#, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiline String Literal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp)

I'm probably not asking the right questions of Google to find my answer.  I just want to keep my code neat without having a really long string on one line.  I want to move to the next line without breaking the string.

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE players SET firstname = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 'Jamie' WHEN 2 THEN 'Steve' WHEN 3 THEN 'Paula' END WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
```

For example, I would like to break this into two lines without affecting the string.  All help would be appreciated.

Comment: @ColeJohnson \n won't work on source file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect what you want is to use the `@` for verbatim string literals; the advantage of verbatim strings is that escape sequences are not processed, and that they can span multiple lines.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE players 
                    SET firstname = 
                      CASE id 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Jamie' 
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'Steve' 
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Paula' 
                      END 
                    WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
```

Comment: This was perfect.  I'm sure the others work equally as well.  Thanks to all who helped.

Answer (score 4):

Use **`@`** symbol before string. It will say to compiler that string is multiline.

```
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE players 
                    SET firstname = CASE id 
                        WHEN 1 THEN 'Jamie' 
                        WHEN 2 THEN 'Steve' 
                        WHEN 3 THEN 'Paula' 
                        END WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `@` in fronf of your string. This is called [Verbatim String Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
cmd.CommandText = @"
 UPDATE players 
 SET firstname = CASE id 
                 WHEN 1 THEN 'Jamie' 
                 WHEN 2 THEN 'Steve' 
                 WHEN 3 THEN 'Paula' 
                 END 
 WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE players SET firstname =" +
   " CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 'Jamie' WHEN 2 THEN 'Steve' WHEN 3" + 
   " THEN 'Paula' END WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
```

Comment: @ works as well, keep in mind with the way I showed , you have to remember to space at the beginning of the next line as prevent concatinating 2 words that aren't supposed to be

Comment: @webby68 - its good to remember this as an option , even though it doesn't work quite as cleanly as the @ approach - if you ever have to write the same thing in VB.Net , the @ before a string is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Simpley concatenate your strings as follows:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE players SET firstname = CASE id WHEN 1 " 
cmd.CommandText +="THEN 'Jamie' WHEN 2 THEN 'Steve' WHEN 3 THEN 'Paula' END WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called concatenation:

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE players SET firstname" +
    " = CASE id WHEN 1 THEN 'Jamie' WHEN 2 THEN 'Steve'" +
    " WHEN 3 THEN 'Paula' END WHERE id IN (1,2,3)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
cmd.CommandText = "text text" +
  "text text";
```