# Are there arbitrary byte-array constants in C#

Tags: c#, public-key-encryption

I want to migrate a c++ code to c# , in my c++ code i am using a public key for testing using a hard coded value like this :

```
static unsigned char PubKeyModulus[] = {
"\xCA\x68\x77\....."
"\x17\x55\x79\..."
"\xF5\xD2\...."
"\x2B\xE4\..."
"\x7F\xC5\..."
"\xEA\x19\..."
"\x83\x67\..."
"\x68\xEF\..."
"\x57\x72\..."
"\x0F\xE5\..."
"\xD0\xBD\..."
"\x21\x21\..."
"\x11\x63\..."
"\x05\xFB\..."
"\x44\x7A\..."
"\xD3\x19\..."
};
```

how can i use this value in C# code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiline String Literal in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

Note that while `char` is a single-byte type in C++, it's a two-byte type in C#. You want `byte` in C#.

As for the specific question, wouldn't the following work?

```
static readonly byte PubKeyModulus[] = {
0xCA, 0x68, 0x77, ...
0x17, 0x55, 0x79, ...
0xF5, 0xD2, ...
0x2B, 0xE4, ...
0x7F, 0xC5, ...
0xEA, 0x19, ...
0x83, 0x67, ...
0x68, 0xEF, ...
0x57, 0x72, ...
0x0F, 0xE5, ...
0xD0, 0xBD, ...
0x21, 0x21, ...
0x11, 0x63, ...
0x05, 0xFB, ...
0x44, 0x7A, ...
0xD3, 0x19, ...
};
```

(Where `...` is replaced by more byte values, of course)

If not, please explain why not.

Comment: this is the mothode's signature in c++ 
`extern __declspec( dllexport )
    int CardAuthenticate(
        IN const unsigned char* PubAuthKey,
        IN unsigned int PubAuthKeySize );
`
@PeterSmith i tried your solution but it's not working.

this is my calling for the method in my C# code
`[DllImport("MyDLL.dll")]
  public static extern Int32 CardAuthenticate(byte[] Data, ref int CleSize);`

Comment: Declaring a `byte[]` data structure is different from passing it to some unmanaged code via interop. If the above addresses your question about how to do the declaration, but you still have a question about how to pass it, you should accept this and post a new question showing what you've tried, explaining what it did and how that's different from what you wanted.