# What's wrong with this format string in c#

Tags: c#, string, formatting

I am trying to declring a string like this :

```
string query = @"SELECT foo, bar
FROM table
WHERE id = 42";
```

as explained in the [Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp)

My Text is :

```
editor.DocumentText = @"<html><body> <div align=\"left\"> <font face=\"Arial\" color=\"#0000ff\">
            <span style=\"font-size:8pt\">Multi-Room DVR Splash screen is displayed with the following:</span></font>";
```

but it gives error ,

I do understand that i can use `+`  and give multi line string :

```
editor.DocumentText = "<html><body> <div align=\"left\"> <font face=\"Arial\" color=\"#0000ff\">"+
            "<span style=\"font-size:8pt\">Multi-Room DVR Splash screen is displayed with the following:</span></font>";
```

This even works fine .

My doubt is why the 1st method of declaring is giving error , but same is working for `query` example .

Comment: Because when using `@`, you can't escape `"` with `\\`.

Comment: @CodeCaster you do need to escape `"` but you double it up `@"escaped quotes """` rather than `\"`

Comment: @Meehow yeah I was trying to post that, but backslashes and backticks are hard in Markdown.

Comment: In your particular case I would suggest using a `'` in the html rather than a `"` as it will be more readable.

Comment: Try to escape the double quotes by "" instead of \".

Comment: Thanks, using "" (double quotes ) and  '(single quotes) both got working