# Unable to convert php regex to C# regex

Tags: c#, php, regex

I want to count links which are having special symbol (underscore) . I have written regex its working fine in an online editor/php editor, but not working in C# code:

```
<
  (?<Tag_Name>(a)|img)\b
  [^>]*?
  \b(?<URL_Type>(?(2)href|src))
  \s*=\s*
  (?:"(?<URL>(?:\\.|[^\\"_#?&]++)*(?:_|(?<Query>[#?&]))(?:\\.|[^"\\]++)*)"
  |  '(?<URL>(?:\\.|[^\\'_#?&]++)*(?:_|(?<Query>[#?&]))(?:\\.|[^'\\]++)*)')
```

but in C# code its giving compilation error

```
MatchCollection underscoreLinks = Regex.Matches(strIn, "<(?<Tag_Name>(a)|img)\b[^>]*?\b(?<URL_Type>(?(2)href|src)) \s*=\s*(?:"(?<URL>(?:\\.|[^\\"_#?&]++)*(?:_|(?<Query>[#?&]))(?:\\.|[^"\\]++)*)"|  '(?<URL>(?:\\.|[^\\'_#?&]++)*(?:_|(?<Query>[#?&]))(?:\\.|[^'\\]++)*)')", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Comment: can u check it this

<
  (?<Tag_Name>(a)|img)\b
  [^>]*?
  \b(?<URL_Type>(?(2)href|src))
  \s*=\s*
  (?:"(?<URL>(?:\\.|[^\\"_]++)*_(?:\\.|[^"\\]++)*)"
  |  '(?<URL>(?:\\.|[^\\'_]++)*_(?:\\.|[^'\\]++)*)')

its not working same issue

Comment: It's exactly the same issue, so the same answer applies. I believe if you understand the answer I wrote you'd be able to correct this on your own.

Comment: yes i corrected it. its over

Comment: but unable to do this ...please help

<img(?![^>]*\balt\s*=\s*"[^"]+")[^>]+>

Comment: Did you escape the quotes (item **2** in my answer)?

Comment: hai this is giving compilation error , can u convert to c# plz

<img(?![^>]*\balt\s*=\s*"[^"]+")[^>]+>

Comment: I'm sorry, but I believe that is already covered in the answer. I'd recommend reading this post: [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1928943/5290909)

Comment: should i add one more double quote at the place of double quote?

Comment: Why don't you try :)

Comment: To test a .Net RegEx you can try http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: @Oliver The syntax to escape a quote is not related to regex

Answer (score 3):

There are some things you need to correct:

1. You're using single backslashes, which are parsed by the .net interpreter before they're passed to regex. Use a [verbatim string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) instead, ie: `@"pattern"`
2. You have unescaped quotes in your string. To escape them in a verbatim string, use [2 double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100273/5290909): `@"the ""pattern"" with quotes"`.
3. [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) does not support [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). Use an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) instead. i.e: change `[^\\"_#?&]++` to `(?>[^\\"_#?&]+)`.
4. You can use the same multiline syntax, ignoring whitespace, using [`RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx).

---

```
string pattern = @"
    <
      (?<Tag_Name>(a)|img)\b
      [^>]*?
      \b(?<URL_Type>(?(2)href|src))
      \s*=\s*
      (?:""(?<URL>(?>\\.|[^\\""_#?&]+)*(?:_|(?<Query>[#?&]))(?>\\.|[^""\\]+)*)""
      |  '(?<URL>(?>\\.|[^\\'_#?&]+)*(?:_|(?<Query>[#?&]))(?>\\.|[^'\\]+)*)')
    ";

Regex re = new Regex( pattern, 
                      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline
                      | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

MatchCollection underscoreLinks = re.Matches(text);
```

<kbd>[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/slLCcT)</kbd>