# Using double quotes in PowerShell script executed from C# application

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to execute a PowerShell script from within a Windows Forms app written in C# on VS.

The issue I have is my PowerShell script has a lot of quote marks in it and I have no idea how to insert that into my code.

Here is my PowerShell script:

```bsh
param([string]$inParam)
$Username = 'SERVER\domain_user'
$Password = 'password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER_TEST -Authentication Default -ScriptBlock {&"D:\Programs\myapplication.cmd" $inParam} -Credential $Cred
```

How would I go about inserting this into the following C# code?

```cs
using (PowerShell powershellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    powershellInstance.AddScript();
}
```

Hope this is enough details and thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [multiline string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1100265/1630171) and escape the nested double quotes by doubling them:

```cs
string script = @"param([string]$inParam)
$Username = 'SERVER\domain_user'
$Password = 'password'
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$pass
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER_TEST -Authentication Default -ScriptBlock {&""D:\Programs\myapplication.cmd"" $inParam} -Credential $Cred";
```

Comment: Perfect! I did try this but missed the nested double quotes which was causing my issue.