# First Chance Exception ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am having some trouble figuring out what is wrong with my code as soon as
the debugger hits the execute query a first chance exception is thrown, I know it is not the query since I tested it out in SQL Management Studio. If anyone could give me some insight as to what is wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code,

```
/// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            string con_string = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CHDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con_string);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1) AS Floor, COUNT(*) AS Patients" +
                                            "FROM Admissions" +
                                            "WHERE SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3')" +
                                            "AND DischargeDate IS NULL" +
                                            "GROUP BY SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1)", con);

            try {
                using (con) {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    chtFloor.Series["Series1"].Name = "currentPatients";
                    chtFloor.Series["currentPatients"].Points.DataBindXY(reader, "Floor", "Patients");

                    chtFloor.Width = 600;
                    chtFloor.Height = 600;
                    chtFloor.BorderSkin.SkinStyle = BorderSkinStyle.Emboss;
                    chtFloor.Titles.Add(new Title("Number of Current Patients on Each Floor", Docking.Top, new Font("Arial", 20f), Color.Black));
                    chtFloor.Titles.Add(new Title("Nursing Unit", Docking.Bottom, new Font("Arial", 12f), Color.Black));
                    chtFloor.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("AliceBlue");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the thrown exception?

Comment: Note that string concatenation is sign of attempt to add user's input into query. I'd recommend checking out [multiline string literals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp) answer and obviously use parametrized queries when you actually attempt to pass input to your query.

Comment: (Question in current state has good chance to be closed as typographical error - not really sure how to fix it so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add spaces when concatenating the strings:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "SELECT SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1) AS Floor, COUNT(*) AS Patients " +
    "FROM Admissions " +
    "WHERE SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1) IN ('1', '2', '3') " +
    "AND DischargeDate IS NULL " +
    "GROUP BY SUBSTRING(NursingUnitID, 1, 1)", con);
```