# How to run load of html body declared in C# and JavaScript declared in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, code-behind

I need to create a functinality in which I have to create the Html file in which is written in c# like this

```
string strHTMLGrid = "";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<body id='body1'  onload='OpenCube()'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<h1>" + sHeading + "</h1>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<div id='EVObject_xml' style='margin: 0px; position: absolute; top: 12px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; '>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<object name='EVObject' width='100%' height='100%' id='EVObject' codebase='" + sUrlHtml + "' lang='en-US' classid='clsid:80AC1200-0BBE-499A-A9E9-5F334DBC8E89'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<param name='Server' value='" + sServername1 + "'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<param name='Server' value='" + sTheme1 + "'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<param name='Server' value='" + sHeading + "'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "</object>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "</div>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<div id='ribbon'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<div id='backstage - container'> </div>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "</div>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "</body>";
```

In this I have declared a function  on load a function named opencube() and I need to call it in c# on the load of the body

```
    string jScriptValidator;
    jScriptValidator = "<script> function OpenCube()" + "\n";
    jScriptValidator = "<script> { \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Enable(UIAuthorisationType.UIAuthorisationToolbar, true); \n ";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Enable(UIAuthorisationType.UIAuthorisationTabBar, true); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.TabBarPosition = TabBarPositionType.TabBarPositionBottom; \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.UIAuthorisationToolbarText, false); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.ToolBar.LargeButtons = false; \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Enable(UIAuthorisationType.UIAuthorisationLocalViews, false)\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.ActionAuthorisationDataEntry, false);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.ActionAuthorisationSaveView, true);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.ActionAuthorisationExport, true);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.ActionAuthorisationExportToExcel, true);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.ViewLocations = 'General =/';\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.object.attachEvent('NeedDataSourceCredentials', DataSourceCredentials); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Enable(EVObject.object.attachEvent('NeedServerCredentials', ServerCredentials);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Views.Open('/ Outdb / mis');\n";
    jScriptValidator += " LeaveBackstage(); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "ExpandRibbons(false); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "ShowBackstage(false); \n";
    jScriptValidator += " } </script>";
```

Now how to connect both of them i don't know.

Comment: FYI [Multiline String Literal in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What do you mean by **connect both of them**? Do you want to insert the script in the HTML?

Comment: I need to Make a Html File dynamically in which on a click of button html file genrated with that some parameters are their given by client..to open the things in javascript.

Comment: Yes I need to insert the script so that on the load of body the javascript function will get called in C#

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to insert the string containing the script inside the html string. In order to do that first declare the script string:

I believe you hace declared the opening of the script tag twice, and maybe you also need to add a document.ready function in order for the script to execute correctly once your html loads.

```
   string jScriptValidator;
    jScriptValidator = "<script> function OpenCube()" + "\n";
    jScriptValidator = "<script> { \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Enable(UIAuthorisationType.UIAuthorisationToolbar, true); \n ";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Enable(UIAuthorisationType.UIAuthorisationTabBar, true); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.TabBarPosition = TabBarPositionType.TabBarPositionBottom; \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.UIAuthorisationToolbarText, false); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.ToolBar.LargeButtons = false; \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Enable(UIAuthorisationType.UIAuthorisationLocalViews, false)\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.ActionAuthorisationDataEntry, false);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.ActionAuthorisationSaveView, true);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.ActionAuthorisationExport, true);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Allow(ActionAuthorisationType.ActionAuthorisationExportToExcel, true);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.ViewLocations = 'General =/';\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.object.attachEvent('NeedDataSourceCredentials', DataSourceCredentials); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Enable(EVObject.object.attachEvent('NeedServerCredentials', ServerCredentials);\n";
    jScriptValidator += "EVObject.Views.Open('/ Outdb / mis');\n";
    jScriptValidator += " LeaveBackstage(); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "ExpandRibbons(false); \n";
    jScriptValidator += "ShowBackstage(false); \n";
    jScriptValidator += " } </script>";
```

Once you have your script tag you can insert it inside the html string. Check out the line before the body tag closes

```
string strHTMLGrid = "";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<body id='body1'  onload='OpenCube()'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<h1>" + sHeading + "</h1>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<div id='EVObject_xml' style='margin: 0px; position: absolute; top: 12px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; '>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<object name='EVObject' width='100%' height='100%' id='EVObject' codebase='" + sUrlHtml + "' lang='en-US' classid='clsid:80AC1200-0BBE-499A-A9E9-5F334DBC8E89'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<param name='Server' value='" + sServername1 + "'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<param name='Server' value='" + sTheme1 + "'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<param name='Server' value='" + sHeading + "'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "</object>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "</div>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<div id='ribbon'>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "<div id='backstage - container'> </div>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "</div>";
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + jScriptValidator;
strHTMLGrid = strHTMLGrid + "</body>";
```

Is this what you wanted??

Comment: I dnt know how on load of body in html (c#) how my javascript (c#) will get called and html will get genrated...right now i am when i press f5 it comes to  strHTMLGrid  but dont call  OpenCube() in javascript in C#

Comment: Ok, remember javascript is the language of the browser and C# runs in the server. So you need to separate code executed in the server from the one executed in the browser. Maybe you can solve this by loading the content asynchronously via ajax. Is that a possible scenario for your problem?

Comment: No Austin, Its not possible I need to create the html file in seerver side and thats why javascript too written der only on server side code in form of C# and than i need to pass the parameters in form of ' Parameter name'

Comment: maybe a possible solution is to get the object EVObject by id inside your script instead of passing it as a parameter. You can do this by adding the line var EVObject = document.getElementById("EVObject"); in the begining of your script string, and then handling it inside the function