# Double quotes in c# doesn't allow multiline

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

e.g.

```
string str = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + title + "" + message + "\"}}";
```

I need to make it as for readability:

```
 string str = "
 {
   \"aps\":
         {
             \"alert\":\"" + title + "" + message + "\"
         }
 }";
```

How to achieve this, please suggest.

Comment: You can use single quotes instead of double.

Comment: @X-TECH: Not if the OP wants to end up with valid JSON.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you *really* need to do this in a string literal, I'd use a verbatim string literal (the `@` prefix). In verbatim string literals you need to use `""` to represent a double quote. I'd suggest using interpolated string literals too, to make the embedding of `title` and `message` cleaner. That does mean you need to double the `{{` and `}}` though. So you'd have:

```
string title = "This is the title: ";
string message = "(Message)";
string str = $@"
{{
   ""aps"":
   {{
       ""alert"":""{title}{message}""
   }}
}}";
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Output:

```
{
   "aps":
   {
       "alert":"This is the title: (Message)"
   }
}
```

However, this is still more fragile than simply building up JSON using a JSON API - if the title or message contain quotes for example, you'll end up with invalid JSON. I'd just use Json.NET, for example:

```
string title = "This is the title: ";
string message = "(Message)";
JObject json = new JObject
{
    ["aps"] = new JObject 
    { 
        ["alert"] = title + message 
    }
};
Console.WriteLine(json.ToString());
```

That's *much* cleaner IMO, as well as being more robust.

Comment: @furqanms: Sorry, I don't know what you mean. The code I've given doesn't produce any extra braces, and it's unclear what code you're using.

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake, JObject is great for readability, Thanks @Jon Skeet

Comment: Your Json.NET for me is the correct answer, it worked for me and got me out of a hole during development of an app too so thanks for sharing

Answer (score 4):

You could use what X-Tech has said, use additional concatenation operators ('+') on every line, or use the symbol '@':

```
 string str = @"
         {
           'aps':
                 {
                     'alert':'" + title + "" + message + @"'
                 }
         }";
```

Since its a JSON, you can use single quotes instead of double quotes.

About '@': [Multiline String Literal in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp)

Comment: note here the @ is needed in the 3rd last line towards the end too, because a new multi line string is starting. Anytime you start a new multi line string, put the '@' symbol.

Comment: Single quotes aren't really valid in JSON. They work in many parsers, but they violate https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for pointing that out.
But I don't see how one could use only double quotes and have a clean multi line string without using single quotes...

Comment: See my answer for a couple of options.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for that answer, learnt something new today.