# How to write a code as string variable (C#)

Tags: c#, string, escaping, character

I'm working on exam in which when the student asked to something like (declare if statement) he will answer in Rich text box.

the question is: I want to search for the input of the student in that box, and therefore, I must declare a string that contains the code (as string) something like that:

```
string check = "            string stat = "new";
            if (stat == "new")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stat);
            }
";
```

However, the problem is that, the escape characters and the other preserved voids such as (if).

Briefly: I want to create string that contains a code.

NOTE: I have tried the @ and putting \ before escape characters, but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Look into verbatim string literals or quote the special characters (including backslash) with backslash (`\`).

Comment: Hard-coding large strings will soon become problematic. Investigate storing them in resources or external files.

Comment: Storing your code-strings in files/resources is the preferred solution. But if you insist on using hard-coded strings, use a StringBuiler and append code lines one by one.

Comment: @HimBromBeere This is definitely NOT a duplicate of that question. It's not about compiling and executing that code!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp

Comment: If you want to use a verbatim string, prefix with @, but do not use a \ to escape quotes. Instead use double quotes:   @"   string stat = ""new"";"

Comment: yes, but still the problem with the keywords like (if) and console.writeline

Comment: “I have tried the @ and putting \ before escape characters, but it didn't work”? Then you did it wrong. You need to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49394014/edit) your question to show us what you tried. And you need to explain what “it didn't work” means. It shows you an error? You need to tell us the erro as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is called the escape sequence and looks like \ concatenated with " (or another symbol):

```
string check = " ... \" ...";
```

Where \"  means "

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get it, can you write for me to clarify

Comment: well in the string I showed, the " is part of the string, which is what you ask for if I'm correct, or I don't understand your problem.