# How to store a code into string data type?

Tags: string, variables, store

all what i need to know is how to store a code like the below into string variable

```
if (status == "admin")
{
   Messegebox.Show("Hello");
}
```

Note that: I have tried @ and \ but the result is still some redlines .

Comment: We told you the [previous time you asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394014/h) to **post your code**. No one can tell you why you get “some redlines” until after you tell us how you “have tried @ and \”.

Comment: i think you see the code in the question!

Comment: You showed us the code you want to “store” but not how you “have tried @ and \”. That is where your mistake is.

Comment: do i have to explain ABC of programming for you to understand -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use '\' to escape double quotes within the string and '\n' to reflect new lines:

```
{String myCode = "if (status == \"admin\")\n{\n    Messegebox.Show(\"Hello\");\n}";}
```