# Erro Syntax Sql Join in c# with sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I Have some error when i add sql inner join 
Here's error

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'SellingDetail'.
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolea'Lks_itSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Lks_itSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   'Lks_itSoftware.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Lks_itSoftware.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
>   n asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
>      at Lks_itSoftware.InputSellingForm.showData() in E:\Zuhdan\Sekolah\LKS\Lks_itSoftware\Lks_itSoftware\InputSellingForm.cs:line 44
>   ClientConnectionId:ddcfb16a-208c-40c0-be48-b3a296ef673c
>   Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15

and Here's my code

```
tring query =  "SELECT Food.FoodName, SellingDetail.Qty, Food.Price, SellingDetail.Price AS Expr1" +
                        "FROM ((SellingDetail INNER JOIN" +
                        "Food ON SellingDetail.FoodId = Food.Foodid)INNER JOIN" +
                        "SellingHeader ON SellingDetail.SellingId = SellingHeader.SellingId)INNER JOIN(" +
                        "Employee ON SellingHeader.EmployeeId = Employee.EmployeeId)";
```

Comment: What is the **exact** value of `query` when the issue occurs?

Comment: `JOIN" + "Food` You are missing a space between those words. And a number of others.

Comment: `AS Expr1" + "FROM ((SellingDetail INNER JOIN" +` Don't concatenate SQL like that. As you can see, you will only fail do write correct code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp

Answer (score -2):

If you did some basic troubleshooting - printing the string - you'd see that you need to put a space before each closing quote. i.e.

```
string query =  "SELECT Food.FoodName, SellingDetail.Qty, Food.Price, 
 SellingDetail.Price AS Expr1 " +
            "FROM ((SellingDetail INNER JOIN " +
            "Food ON SellingDetail.FoodId = Food.Foodid)INNER JOIN " +
            "SellingHeader ON SellingDetail.SellingId = 
 SellingHeader.SellingId)INNER JOIN(" +
            "Employee ON SellingHeader.EmployeeId = Employee.EmployeeId)";
```

Comment: With almost 11k, you should know already that typo questions should be closed instead of answered. Also, there is absolutely no point in all those concatenations when you could have just made it a constant string literal

Comment: it seems more like a typo to me. It seems like the poster doesn't actually know that you need to do this. Regardless, I'm sure the OP has already abandoned the question.

Comment: @Camilo About the constant; you are right that it should be one, but adding the `const` keyword would suffice, the concatenations can stay as-is as the compiler takes care of them.

Comment: Funny thing is, for once I decided I would answer instead of comment (I almost always comment) and you guys are _ruthless_ haha

Comment: @pfx I am very aware of that, but it is much cleaner (at least to me) to have a literal than concatenations. I wasn't referring to adding `const` though

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I think you meant Entity Framework? Haha, yeah, that's most likely the case here.

Comment: We are quibbling over how the query should be written here and my understanding is that if you were using EF you would write the query in LINQ