# What is the correct way of using (INSERT SELECT FROM WHERE) query in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I'm making a form on C# that inserts data in a table with a where clause, but it's not working. I think the syntax of my query is the problem but I can't solve it.

This is the one that I tried that's working, but I need an insert query with a where clause.

```
SqlCommand addEmp = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_Expenses " +
                "(InvestedMoney,EstimatedServingCount,MealName) " +
                "VALUES (@inv, @est, @mname)", conn);
addEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", textBox1.Text);
addEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inv", textBox2.Text);
addEmp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@est", textBox3.Text);

conn.Open();
addEmp.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

I tried this code below:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tbl_Meal" +                                 
    " ExpensesID, MealName, MealPrice, ImageName, Imageblob)" +
    "SELECT ExpensesID, @mname, @mprice, @imname, @img " +
    "FROM tbl_Expenses" +
    "WHERE MealName = '"+textBox1.Text+"'",conn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mname", textBox1.Text);                      
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mprice", textBox4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imname", textBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image, photo.Length).Value = photo;

conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: I **strongly** suspect your main issue is `"from tbl_Expenses" +
                                "WHERE` You missed a space before `WHERE`. You can discover these kinds of things in future, by yourself, by looking at the value of `cmd.CommandText`.

Comment: I think I'm just really tired that's why i didn't see that I'm missing a space there,
the deadline for my project is tomorrow that's why i didn't have a sleep in the past 12 hours.
anyways thank you so much, your respond is faster than my group mates lol

Comment: It happens to the best of us @krljde. Perhaps close your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp may help you avoid these kinds of issues in future.

Comment: using @ (escape sequence modifier) infront of the string you can do multiline steings and dont have to worry about such things as missing spaces

Comment: You should probably refactor this to not pass `textBox1.Text` through directly in your where clause.  Doing so is outright dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

This section is missing a space between the lines:

```
"from tbl_Expenses" +
"WHERE MealName = '"
```

so the sql code references a table named `tbl_ExpensesWHERE`, gives the table an alias of `MealName`, and then has an out-of-place `=`.

But you should also already know from the use of parameters elsewhere it is *NOT* okay to substitute `textBox1.Text` into the query like that. **NEVER** do that. *Not even once.* Not even for practice/learning code!

There are some other poor practices in here, but that was the worst. Here's a better pattern:

```
string sql = @"
INSERT into tbl_Meal
    (ExpensesID,MealName,MealPrice,ImageName,Imageblob)
SELECT
    ExpensesID,@mname,@mprice,@mname,@img 
FROM tbl_Expenses
WHERE MealName = @mname";

using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    //wild guess at column types. Use actual column types/size FROM THE DATABASE
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = textBox1.Text;  
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@mprice", SQlDbType.Decimal, 18, 8).Value = textBox4.Text;
    //use the size of the column here, not the length of the photo
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image, 8000).Value = photo;

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Parameters.AddWithValue()` use `Parameters.Add()` and also use correct datatypes, for example `EstimatedServingCount` seems to be an int, but however `AddWithValue` can not know that:

```
addEmp.Parameters.Add("@mname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
addEmp.Parameters.Add("@inv", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
addEmp.Parameters.Add("@est", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox3.Text;
```

Comment: The code above is just a test of my original code, that's i didn't bother to fix the minor errors in that code. Your answer wont help with my main problem tho, thanks anyways