# Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collection.Generic.List<char>> to string[]

Tags: c#, generics, encryption

I use this code (found here [c sharp helper aes encryption](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/09/convert-between-byte-arrays-and-hexadecimal-strings-in-c/)) to encrypt a string and the encrypted string I want to save to a file.

```
#region "Encrypt Strings and Byte[]"
    // Note that extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class.

    // Encrypt or decrypt the data in in_bytes[] and return the result.
    public static byte[] CryptBytes(string password, byte[] in_bytes, bool encryptAES)
    {
        // Make an AES service provider.
        AesCryptoServiceProvider aes_provider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

        // Find a valid key size for this provider.
        int key_size_bits = 0;
        for (int i = 4096; i > 1; i--)
        {
            if (aes_provider.ValidKeySize(i))
            {
                key_size_bits = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        Debug.Assert(key_size_bits > 0);
        Console.WriteLine("Key size: " + key_size_bits);

        // Get the block size for this provider.
        int block_size_bits = aes_provider.BlockSize;

        // Generate the key and initialization vector.
        byte[] key = null;
        byte[] iv = null;
        byte[] salt = { 0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0xF1, 0xF0, 0xEE, 0x21, 0x22, 0x45 };
        MakeKeyAndIV(password, salt, key_size_bits, block_size_bits, out key, out iv);


        // Make the encryptor or decryptor.
        ICryptoTransform crypto_transform;
        if (encryptAES)
        {
            crypto_transform = aes_provider.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);
        }
        else
        {
            crypto_transform = aes_provider.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        }

        // Create the output stream.
        using (MemoryStream out_stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Attach a crypto stream to the output stream.
            using (CryptoStream crypto_stream = new CryptoStream(out_stream,
                crypto_transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                // Write the bytes into the CryptoStream.
                crypto_stream.Write(in_bytes, 0, in_bytes.Length);
                try
                {
                    crypto_stream.FlushFinalBlock();
                }
                catch (CryptographicException)
                {
                    // Ignore this exception. The password is bad.
                }
                catch
                {
                    // Re-throw this exception.
                    throw;
                }

                // return the result.
                return out_stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    // String extensions to encrypt and decrypt strings.
    public static byte[] EncryptAES(this string the_string, string password)
    {
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ascii_encoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] plain_bytes = ascii_encoder.GetBytes(the_string);
        return CryptBytes(password, plain_bytes, true);
    }
    public static string DecryptAES(this byte[] the_bytes, string password)
    {
        byte[] decrypted_bytes = CryptBytes(password, the_bytes, false);
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ascii_encoder = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        return ascii_encoder.GetString(decrypted_bytes);
    }
    public static string CryptString(string password, string in_string, bool encrypt)
    {
        // Make a stream holding the input string.
        byte[] in_bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(in_string);
        using (MemoryStream in_stream = new MemoryStream(in_bytes))
        {
            // Make an output stream.
            using (MemoryStream out_stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Encrypt.
                CryptStream(password, in_stream, out_stream, true);

                // Return the result.
                out_stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                using (StreamReader stream_reader = new StreamReader(out_stream))
                {
                    return stream_reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Convert a byte array into a readable string of hexadecimal values.
    public static string ToHex(this byte[] the_bytes)
    {
        return ToHex(the_bytes, false);
    }
    public static string ToHex(this byte[] the_bytes, bool add_spaces)
    {
        string result = "";
        string separator = "";
        if (add_spaces) separator = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < the_bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            result += the_bytes[i].ToString("x2") + separator;
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Convert a string containing 2-digit hexadecimal values into a byte array.
    public static byte[] ToBytes(this string the_string)
    {
        List<byte> the_bytes = new List<byte>();
        the_string = the_string.Replace(" ", "");

        for (int i = 0; i < the_string.Length; i += 2)
        {
            the_bytes.Add(
                byte.Parse(the_string.Substring(i, 2),
                    System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
        }
        return the_bytes.ToArray();
    }


    #endregion // Encrypt Strings and Byte[]
```

With the code above you will get a list byte with this function it wil be converted to a list char

```
 // Return a string that represents the byte array
    // as a series of hexadecimal values separated
    // by a separator character.
    public static string ToHex(this byte[] the_bytes, char separator)
    {
        return BitConverter.ToString(the_bytes, 0).Replace('-', separator);
    }
```

I get my data from a list of strings encrypt them like this and want to write them to a file

```
       var encryptedLines = (from line in output
                                      select Helper.ToHex(Encryption.EncryptAES(line, symKey),' ').ToList());
```

but `File.WriteAllLines(fileWrite, encryptedLines);` always give me the exception form the title or if i write result it of course just writes down System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char] because it doesnt realy convert the datatype to list string

That beeing said I dont understand why I cant just write all lines of chars to a file?

I tried `.ToString()` or `var result = encryptedLines.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();`

Comment: Change `ToList` to `ToArray`

Comment: i now made this `List<string> output2 = new List<string>();

                foreach (var line in encryptedLines)
                {
                    var noob = String.Concat(line);
                    output2.Add(noob);
                }`

Comment: `var result = encryptedLines.Select(x => new string(x.ToArray())).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may either convert your char list to char array or convert the char list to a string using

```
 listOfChars.Aggregate("", (str, x) => str + x);
```

The second approach is not recommended as it has a quadratic complexity (check the comments on this answer)

---

UPDATE:

After the comments by Mr. Lee I checked back again and I find this to be way more efficient:

```
listOfChars.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(""), (str, x) => str.Append(x));
```

Comment: This approach is quadratic in the length of the list.

Comment: Please provide me with feedback regarding why you would vote this down?

Comment: @Lee I can't see why it's quadratic, it's linear

Comment: `str + x` must copy `str` in order to append the char `x` on the end so you're creating `n` copies of strings of length `0, 1, 2, ... n` which is quadradic.

Comment: @Lee +1 You're right!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1328159/4259962
Thanks very much.... Editing the answer

Comment: what is the better way, the aproach that i posted or this one here?

Comment: I guess the updated version is better, your solution is the same as my old one

Comment: okay thanks for you help worked perfectly ill use that one, sadly i cant upvote just yet :(