# How does the c# compiler concat strings

Tags: c#, string, string-concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does C# optimize the concatenation of string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288794/does-c-sharp-optimize-the-concatenation-of-string-literals)

```
string foo = "bar1" + "bar2" + "bar3";
```

Does the c# compiler internally apply the string.Concat method ?

Then it would be better to use the + operator for the readability sake.

Comment: yes its a dupe, See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/288913/368070) answer on the same post.

Answer (score 3):

With literals, this is equivalent to:

```
string foo = "bar1bar2bar3";
```

No concatenation is performed- they are combined at compile time into a constant.

Comment: I think he meant in a case where you'd say `string foo = "bar: " + bar + " (bar bar)";` where `bar` is unknown at compile time.

Comment: Possibly, but he didn't write the question that way.