# Is there a way to force a line wrap in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Take this example.

```
MessageBox.Show("You cannot create an incident and also provide a Case Number\nPlease choose one or the other");
```

I would like to have it on two lines like this, but without the + operator

```
MessageBox.Show("You cannot create an incident and also provide a Case Number\n" + 
                "Please choose one or the other");
```

But I was wondering "is there some escape character where I can do it without the string concatenation?"

Answer (score 3):

You can do this (note you *cannot* indent the second line or the indentation will become part of the string):

```
MessageBox.Show(@"You cannot create an incident and also provide a Case Number
Please choose one or the other");
```

But in reality you should not worry about using the `+` string concatenation as [the compiler will optimize it away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288794/does-c-sharp-optimize-the-concatenation-of-string-literals).

Answer (score 3):

You could make it a [verbatim](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gusperez/archive/2005/08/10/450257.aspx) string:

```
string msg = @"You cannot create an incident and also provide a Case Number
Please choose one or the other";
MessageBox.Show( msg );
```

Comment: That will add an extra new line, and cause the second line to be indented quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
MessageBox.Show(@"You cannot create an incident and also provide a Case Number 
Please choose one or the other");
```

Answer (score -2):

Use the following:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("This is my first line. {0} This is my second line. {0}" +
    "And this is my third line.", Environment.NewLine));
```

Remember, this only works in certain scenarios. For instance in HTML you'd need to use `<br />` instead of `Environment.NewLine`, but the system is the same.

Comment: IMHO this is even uglier, will definitely be a performance hit, and *still* doesn't get rid of the concatenation.

Comment: In that case follow the answer of @tim-schmelter, but that does *only* work on Windows machines with Windows Forms' MessageBoxes. The solution I propose can be used also with strings on a .resx file, supplying what the character of NewLine is in every application, such as if you use the same message both in Web and Desktop, for instance.

Comment: @IsaacLlopis. Only works in messageboxes? It's a string literal, it will work wherever it's in scope.

Comment: Environment.NewLine is not a <br/> for instance. If you plan to use the same text for a Web application, \n characters will not be rendered properly because those are not proper formatted New Lines for HTML.