# Specific(exact) characters from char array to string C#

Tags: c#

I just saw in one source code something like this:

```
char[] letters = { 'k', 'n', 'p', 's' };

    for (int d1 = 0; d1 < letters.Length; d1++)
    {
        for (int d2 = 0; d2 < letters.Length; d2++)
        {
            for (int d3 = 0; d3 < letters.Length; d3++)
            {
                for (int d4 = 0; d4 < letters.Length; d4++)
                {
                    string left = ""+ letters[d1] + letters[d2] + letters[d3] + letters[d4];
                }
           }
        }
    }
```

What I am realy wondering is how exactly is that `string strName = "" +....` working. What are these `""` for? I looked wherever I could, but didnt find answer.
Sorry if answer is very easy, I am new in programming, so I will appreciate your understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhere in the [C# Language Specifications](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) (7.8.4 I think) it is written:

> **String concatenation:**
>
> string operator +(string x, string y);
>
> string operator +(string x, object y);
>
> string operator +(object x, string y);
>
> These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation. If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is substituted. **Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method inherited from type object.** If ToString returns null, an empty string is substituted.

So the `+ operator` between a `string` and a `char` converts the `char` to a `string` (through the `.ToString()` method of the char) and concatenates the two.

So for example:

```
char ch = 'x';

string str = "" + ch;
```

is "converted" to

```
string str = "" + ch.ToString();
```

where `ch.ToString()` is `"x"`  (with double quotes, so a `string`)

In the end `"" + something` is a (safe) way to call `.ToString()` for something, safe because it handles the case that `something == null`, by not calling `.ToString()` and returning an empty string.

In your specific case, you can see that line of code as something like:

```
string left = "" + letters[d1].ToString();
left = left + letters[d2].ToString();
left = left + letters[d3].ToString();
left = left + letters[d4].ToString();
```

(in truth it is a little more complex if I remember correctly, because the C# compiler optimizes multiple string concatenations through the use of a single call to `string.Concat`, but this is an implementation detail, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/288913/613130)

Comment: Great anwer, appreciate it!

Comment: For the one that suggested the edit, no, it is wrong. There is an explicit addition between `""` and the first `letters[d1]`. Then the compiler can clearly be clever and remove it, but it is present.

Answer (score 3):

Simple : letters[i] is a char and to cast it to a string "" is added to the expression.

e.g. `int x = 5;`

```
  string str = ""+x;  // "5" as string.
```

Same goes for char to string
:)

Comment: You have got it, but perhaps you should try to expand a little explaining why you cannot build a string just concatenating characters

Comment: Just joined SO. Will keep that in Mind. :)

Comment: Yes, I made the math for that :D but it looks very.. strange. Isn't there more official way to say "Hey, you- character! Go in that string!" I found something like `string someStr = String.Join("",someCh[0],someCh[1],someCh[2]);)`

Comment: or you can use String.Concat(letters[d1] + letters[d2] + letters[d3] + letters[d4]);