# How to fix error "SQLexception was unhandled by user code incorrect syntax near comma

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Any help on where the ',' error is would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my VB code:

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.ArgumentException

Partial Class MeetingAdd
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim strConnection As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ServiceLine_CommitteeConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(strConnection)
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblVotings(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name) , " +
                                       "SELECT C.ID, M.ID, CM.FULL_NAME FROM ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeName C, " +
                                       "ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblMeetings M, ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeMembers CM " +
                                       "WHERE M.ContractCategory    = C.Contract_Category, " +
                                       "AND M.Committee             = C.Committee_Name, " +
                                       "AND CM.Committee            = M.Committee", con)
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        con.Open()

        Dim result As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        con.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Please help. This is very frustrating.

Comment: Get rid of the commas in the WHERE clause

Comment: Probably here: Member_Name) , " +

Comment: @Dee please **do not use `+` for string concatenation**...

Comment: @Codexer according to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288794/does-c-sharp-optimize-the-concatenation-of-string-literals contatenating string literals does not incur the same performance penalty as contatenating in a loop or separate lines. It's for c# but it implies VB works this way too. Unless you mean the OP should use &

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your posted Code you used unusual `','` multiple times.

1> 1st line here:`Member_Name) ,`

2>4th line here `"WHERE M.ContractCategory = C.Contract_Category, " +
                                       "AND M.Committee             = C.Committee_Name,`

Try:

```
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblVotings(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name) " +
                                       " SELECT C.ID, M.ID, CM.FULL_NAME FROM ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeName C, " +
                                       "ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblMeetings M, ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeMembers CM " +
                                       " WHERE M.ContractCategory   = C.Contract_Category " +
                                       "AND M.Committee             = C.Committee_Name " +
                                       "AND CM.Committee            = M.Committee", con)
```

or

```
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblVotings(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name) " +
                                               " SELECT C.ID, M.ID, CM.FULL_NAME FROM ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeName C INNER JOIN  " +
                                               "ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblMeetings M ON C.Contract_Category=M.ContractCategory AND C.Committee_Name=M.Committee INNER JOIN ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeMembers CM ON CM.Committee=M.Committee", con)
```

Edit2:

String concatenation using **+** sign is not good,you can use [Escaping in verbatim strings](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma)

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(@"insert into ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblVotings
(Meeting_ID, Committee_ID, Member_Name)  SELECT 
C.ID, M.ID, CM.FULL_NAME   FROM   ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeName C INNER JOIN ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblMeetings M ON  C.Contract_Category=M.ContractCategory AND 
C.Committee_Name=M.Committee INNER JOIN ServiceLine_Committee.DBO.tblCommitteeMembers CM ON 
CM.Committee=M.Committee", con)
```

Comment: There is still no FROM keyword, unless I'm issing something

Comment: FROM ?? can you tell me, where??i can't find where i missed. @Jeremy

Comment: never mind. the tables are separated by commas too (which is discouraged by the way) and I didn't see the From word. So, I was missing something :)

Comment: ohhhkkk, no problem.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is clear: Its saying `You have an extra comma that SQL doesnt understand syntax for`. The best way to debug this is set your `SQLCommandString` to a variable like `mySQLCommand`

This way you can see what the actual SQL command is being executed. Put a break point in right after you set `mySQLCommand'. Copy that text directly into a Query from`Server Explorer`or into`SQL Server Management Studio` and try to execute it. You will find it failing. Now you can get the query correct and re-paste it back in your code.

A few other notes: You are selecting from multiple tables but you are not clearly defining a relationship. For example:

```
SELECT Name, Car FROM Names, Cars
```

Technically will work. But this is poorly written. A better way is to define how Names and Cars are related. Something like this:

```
SELECT n.name, c.car FROM Names n
JOIN cars c on c.nameid = n.nameid
```